# How to delete visible Desktop.ini, Thumbs.db and album art from My Music

Tags: windows-7, linux, desktop.ini, thumbs.db

How do I delete album art, desktop.ini, and thumbs.db from my music folder in Windows 7? I can see all of these files because I took the hard drive from my old computer and put it in my new one. It now has all of these junk files that the OS does not use, so I want to delete them and get them out of my sight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This did the trick for me, using Windows 7's Power Shell. Saving this answer, in case anyone else has this problem.

```
Get-ChildItem -incl "desktop.ini","thumbs.db","*.jpg" -path "V:\Music" -force -recurse | Remove-Item
```

This should work in Linux, but I've not tested it so I'm not really sure.

```
find ~/music -type f -name "desktop.ini" -delete
find ~/music -type f -name "Thumbs.db" -delete
find ~/music -type f -name "*.jpg" -delete
```

Comment: I've just found out that the `-force` part is crucial.

Comment: I needed to use -Force but this worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent creation of `thumbs.db` in Windows Vista and above (7 etc) by opening the Local Group Policy Editor (<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and enter `gpedit.msc`) and go to;

```
User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components > Windows Explorer
```

<sub>or `File Explorer` for win 8</sub>

And edit `Turn off the caching of thumbnails in hidden thumbs.db files`. `Enable` it and hit `OK`.

To delete ones already created you can `right click` -> `Properties` on the drive from `My Computer`, hit `Disk Cleanup`, tick only `Thumbnails` and hit `OK`.

---

If you cant access the LGPE (e.g. `MMC could not create the snap-in`) or it just plain didn't work you can dabble in the registry;

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Software -> Microsoft -> Windows -> CurrentVersion -> Explorer -> Advanced
```

set `DisableThumbnailCache` to `1`

If `DisableThumbnailCache` doesn't exist, create it as a new `DWORD`

<sub>reboot may or may not be required</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with two one-liners from a command prompt...

First, open up a `cmd` window, then `cd` to your **Music** folder. Then, run the following 2 commands:

`del /s /q /f /a:h ".\*thumbs.db"`

`del /s /q /f /a:s ".\*desktop.ini"`

These will recursively delete all of the desired files in your current directory.

Answer (score 0):

To expand in [Bigbio2002](https://superuser.com/users/29024/bigbio2002)'s answer you can add the cd inside the batch file.

Here's the modified version. I just saved this to the root directory of my NAS folder which is mapped to Z and this will work for any other drive that has a drive letter.

You could go one extra step and add this to a task in Task Scheduler in Windows to run once you log in, which is what I have done.

```
@echo off & title %~nx0 & color 5F & chcp 65001 >NUL
cd /d "%cd%"
echo Cleaning 'thumbs.db' files from %cd% and all of its sub-directories.
echo/
del /s /q /f /a:h ".\*thumbs.db"
```